# RegularExpression Validator Script Html block

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Does anyone know of a RegularExpression Validator or website thats stops script and html tags being used in TextBoxes and TextAreas

Updated:

```
public static string RegexReplace(string strin, string strExp, string strReplace)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(strin, strExp, strReplace);
    }

    public static string RemoveHTML(string strText)
    {
        return RegexReplace(strText, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to prevent a user from inputting data in an input. You "could" use javascript, but then the user "could" disable javascript and do what they want.

You need to sanitize on the **server side** AFTER the user submits the data.

Check out the Microsoft [AntiXSS Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx), and even [MarkDownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) can do this (even if you're not actually using Markdown). Alternatively there's always the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML for you.

HtmlAgilityPack

> PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack

MarkDownSharp

> PM> Install-Package MarkdownSharp

AntiXss

> PM> Install-Package AntiXSS

Do not, I repeat DO NOT [parse html with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!!!!

Comment: Do you mean using OnServerValidate event on the Validator

Comment: no, I mean you need to strip the volatile scripts... sanitize the input... sorry, I'm going to remove the "validate" portion.

Comment: I've updated my post. Something like above would work? it doesn't say script but html instead maybe use for script what do you think

Comment: <please don't parse html with regex> <it's bad news> - oh woops, that would be parsed out with your solution.

Comment: at VERY least use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of regex.

Comment: I might stick with AntiXSS library, HtmlAgilityPack to me just varifies if its Html i need to look into that more.

Comment: Actually, MarkDownSharp does not sanitize user data, it only translates MarkDown code.